# Fetching a value with chrome.storage.local.get and assigning it to a variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In `background.js` in my Google Chrome Extension I have:

```
function getCurrentSurveyID() {
  chrome.storage.local.get(
    "currentSurveyID", function (value) {
      if (typeof value === "undefined") {var surveyID = 0;} else {var surveyID = value;}
      console.log("value of currentSurveyID read as " + surveyID);
      return {id: surveyID};
    }
  );
}
```

Why am I getting:

```
value of currentSurveyID read as [object Object]
Uncaught ReferenceError: surveyID is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:1
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Many thanks.

====

**Update**

I've just discovered the ability to set default values in `chrome.storage.local.get`. The function now reads:

```
function getCurrentSurveyID() {
  chrome.storage.local.get(
    {currentSurveyID: 0}, function (surveyID) {
      console.log("value of currentSurveyID read as " + surveyID);
      return {id: surveyID};
    }
  );
}
```

Behaviour is unchanged, however.

### Update II

I've now got this working using HTML5's local storage instead of Chrome's:

```
function getCurrentSurveyID() {
  value = localStorage["currentSurveyID"] || 0;
  return {id: value};
}
```

However, I'd still be curious to know what error I was making with Chrome's local storage.

Comment: When I run your function, I don't get that error.

Comment: shouldn't it be **var surveyID = value.currentSurveyID;** ? ... in your first code block, when you testing is it undefined or...

Answer (score 1):

localStorage is a very different and synchronous api and you are using different logic. appart from that, the error in your first case is the one shown in the console: your variable is undefined because you never assign anything to it. the code that assigns it a value is inside an if that wont execute. also you are reading the return value incorrectly, look at the docs. it does not return a single value, it returns an object.